# Django & React Deployment on VPS

Tags: django, reactjs, deployment, django-rest-framework

I'm a newbie trying to deploy a Django backed react app. Please advise.

### What I've created:

1. An app initiated with create-react-app, fully functional locally;
2. A Django api serving the data
3. They 'talk' perfectly to each other, but they are built separately

### Questions:

1. I'm not sure how to incorporate them into one app for deployment. [This post](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/#setting-up-react-and-webpack) by VALENTINO GAGLIARDI is very helpful. But it seems like it's not suitable for an app initiated with create-react-app? Should I learn webpack for deployment?
2. I have experience deploying a fully functional Django e-commerce website and it's up and running. Django handles both frontend and backend via many Django templates. I used `Gunicorn` and `Nginx` for serving the website on a VPS (Ubuntu 18). It's all quite confusing for me to deploy ONE website, and it seems to me, with having to serve TWO apps at the same time under one domain name?

Any pointers for what knowledge should I acquire before completing this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I managed to deploy the website. Basically, I've done a few things:

1. I learnt a bit webpack and managed to bundle all the react js files into one `main.js` file
2. Load the `main.js` file like you normally would, at the bottom of the body tag, don't forget to `{% load static %}`
3. Run `python manage.py collectstatic` like you normally would when deploying a django app. It'll collect all the static files including the `main.js`

I'm still trying to figure out how to implement create-react-app bundled js files though. There are so many of them...